# exception during destruction of CComPtr

Tags: exception, visual-c++, com, atl, smart-pointers

I have a member variable declared as

```
CComPtr<IXMLDOMDocument2> m_spXMLDoc;
```

XML document is created like this

```
CoCreateInstance(CLSID_DOMDocument, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
    IID_IXMLDOMDocument2, (void**)&m_spXMLDoc));
```

Now when application exits, an exception is thrown. Callstack is pointing to `p->Release()`

```
~CComPtrBase() throw()
{
   if (p)
      p->Release();
}
```

When I hover over to `p` in VS debugger, it points to some valid memory.

The last callstack points to exception in msxm6

```
msxml6.dll!3d6cXX03()
```

Any suggestions, what could be the reason? I don't think it's a `CComPtr` issue.

Comment: Manual release()s or misuse of other CComPtrs (e.g. through `Attach()`) could be a reason. If everything else looks fine there could also be memory corruption resulting from other problems.

Comment: What is the life time of the object? When is the destructor called?

Comment: Have you figured out the reason yet?  I just encountered a similar problem (except I am using the Debug Interface Access SDK COM classes, but probably the exact com classes used is not the concern).  I suspect it's something related to CComPtr implementation bug or whatever.

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar issue and eventually I found that it is was just a bug. I have to make sure that `CoUninitialize()` is called AFTER the `CComPtr` is destructed. Otherwise, there will be an exception.

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
  CoInitialize(NULL);
  mymain(); 
  //put all logic in a separate function so that CComPtr
  //is destructed before CoUninitialize()
  CoUninitialize();
  return 0;
}
```

Declaring `CComPt`r in the same function as the `CoUninitialize()` call will cause the exception since the destruction occurs after the function terminates.

Comment: An alternative is to put the code declaring an using the `CComPtr` into a nested block. Another alternative is manually calling `CComPtr::Release()`. Both will solve exactly the same problem, just a bit differently.

Answer (score 1):

Do this before your program exits:

```
if( m_spXMLDoc.p )
    m_spXMLDoc.Release();
```

I've seen this before myself.  The issue is related with reference counting (obviously), but I've never cared to look for the reason.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You should create the instance using the member functions of CComPtr:

```
m_spXMLDoc.CoCreateInstance(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at a similar issue where IExplorer rips the com server for the current web page from under the clients.
The result ***seems to be*** that release can't be performed, instead you get com errors like server has disconnected clients.